# Angular controller not registered on XAMPP web service

Tags: angularjs, xampp

I get this error - Error: $controller:ctrlreg A controller with this name is not registered. All of my scripts are loaded, and I added them all in index.html.

[All scripts are loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m118Q.jpg)

My controller:

```
 (function() {
    angular.module("nsoftModule").controller("nsoftController", ["nsoftService", function(nsoftService) {
        var self = this;
        self.service = nsoftService;
    }])
})();
```

My directive:

```
 (function() {
    var weatherMod = angular.module("nsoftModule", []);
    weatherMod.directive("nsoftDirective", function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: "Template/weatherTemplate.html",
            controller: "nsoftController as nsoftCtrl"
        }
    });
 })();
```

My service:

```
 (function() {
    var weatherMod = angular.module("nsoftModule", []);
    weatherMod.service("nsoftService", ["http", function(http) {
        var service = this;
    }]);
})();
```

My module:

```
(function() {
    var weatherMod = angular.module("nsoftModule", []);
})();
```

My template:

```
<div class="container">
   <div ng-controller="nsoftController">
      <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
      <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

My app.js:

```
(function() {
    angular.module("nsoftApp", ["nsoftModule"]);
})();
```

And my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="nsoftApp">
   <head>
      <title>Nsoft App</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <nsoft-directive></nsoft-directive>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="weatherModule.js"></script>
      <script src="Service/weatherService.js"></script>
      <script src="Controller/weatherController.js"></script>
      <script src="Directive/weatherDirective.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the global variable because in you are using anonymous self invoking function variable is only limited to one anonymous function. use like his

```
(function() {
    angular.module("nsoftModule").controller("nsoftController", ["nsoftService", function(nsoftService) {
        var self = this;
        self.service = nsoftService;
    }])
})();

(function() {
    angular.module("nsoftModule").directive("nsoftDirective", function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: "Template/weatherTemplate.html",
            controller: "nsoftController as nsoftCtrl"
        }
    });
})();

//change http to $http 
(function() {
    angular.module("nsoftModule").service("nsoftService", ["$http", function($http) {
        var service = this;
    }]);
})();

(function() {
    angular.module("nsoftModule", []);
})();
```

since controller assign from the directive no need to declare it in the html also

```
<div class="container">
<div >
   <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="nsoftCtrl.name"></p>
   <h1>Hello {{nsoftCtrl.name}}</h1>
</div>

(function() {
    angular.module("nsoftApp", ["nsoftModule"]);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Sachila, but I still get the same error even with your improvements...

Comment: check this .  i will update the answer https://plnkr.co/edit/9d64fOb9QhNgCeKl90VY?p=preview

Comment: Your welcome. don't forget to upvote and mark as answer